# FLAnimatedImage animates when returned from viewcontroller

Tags: xamarin.ios, animated-gif

I have a screen that has a UITableView and in that UITableView is a cell that has a FLAnimatedImageView that upon displaying doesn't animate until the user clicks on a play button or the image itself (much like how Facebook functions).

This all works very well, until the user clicks on a button in the cell that pushes them into a new ViewController.

When the user pops out of that ViewController, the once stopped animation is now animating, I have no idea how to prevent it from doing that, it should *not* be animating when it comes back from the previous screen.

I've tried adding a check to the said button above but that doesn't stop the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, though not completely happy with it to be honest but it works.

if you set Image, it'll disable the animation. Not as smooth as I'd like but it works. Maybe the people behind the library can add a property that'll allow us to disable autoplay in the future.

if anyone gets stuck on this, this is how I solved it.